# Can a cadence end with a secondary dominant?

Tags: cadence

If I ended a 4 measure phrase with a V resolving to a V7/IV chord, would this still be considered a cadence since it concludes the phrase?

When listening to this, it almost feels like an authentic cadence since the progression is basically V-I, just with the added b7 for the secondary chord.

Any thoughts about this?

Comment: can-a-cadence-end-with-a-secondary-dominant. No. Not in a 4 measure phrase.

Comment: So in key C, your last 2 chords would be G and G/F? (G7 with F bass). If so, it's 'imperfect'. Or, is the final chord C7? (V of F).

Comment: @AlbrechtHügli - surely it can end where you want; although it may not sound too good.

Comment: Yes, it can end even before the last chord.

Comment: It always happens to me that I don’t read exactly.  Lennon asks about V/IV. That’s how most marches are modulating in the trio section. But this will contain several periods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cadence is a series of chords that ends a phrase.  So the answer to your question is yes.

There is no theory of music which dictates what you must use for a cadence;  but there are some very common sequences that have acquired names over the course of time.

You can chose to use something unusual instead and, if it ends a phrase (or the whole piece), then that is your cadence.

Answer (score 1):

This could happen in an extended piece. I recently quotet Bach BWV 999 where he’s moldulating to the dominant.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I'd consider it a cadence, especially if the V-to-V7/IV progression has the rhythm of a cadence. I actually ended a strain (and phrase) of one of my ragtime compositions this way...and modulated straight to the subdominant key right after that.